# Save image offline using sqlite Ionic App

Tags: angularjs, image, ionic-framework

I am working on ionic project which needs to work offline. My issue is, how  to save uploaded image offline in sqlite database, and when track any wifi connection, synch to online.

Image uploading online is working fine, using cordova camera plugin and filetransfer plugin.

Comment: why dont u try to keep that inn local and push it when u get a connection

Comment: Whats wrong with the question to rate it negative? I am asking to save image in sqlite db permanently offline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use cordova file plugin's copyfile method to store the image locally, and then save its link in the database for further use. When the wifi is detected, just use that link to upload file to server with same [cordovafile](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/file/) plugin.

```
$cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(sourcePath) { //for capturing image

console.log(sourcePath);
var sourceDirectory = sourcePath.substring(0, sourcePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);  //image file with path url
var sourceFileName = sourcePath.substring(sourcePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, sourcePath.length); //image name
console.log("Copying from : " + sourceDirectory + sourceFileName);
console.log("Copying to : " + cordova.file.dataDirectory + sourceFileName);

//used to store file locally
$cordovaFile.copyFile(sourceDirectory, sourceFileName, 
 cordova.file.dataDirectory, sourceFileName).then(function(success) {
  $scope.fileName = cordova.file.dataDirectory + sourceFileName;
  console.log($scope.fileName, success);
  $scope.propic = $scope.fileName;

}, function(error) {
  console.log(error);
});
}, function(err) {
  console.log(err);
});
```